# Como reconhecer instâncias do MySQL usando Java e permitir a escolha do banco pelo usuário?

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que é requisitado que seja possível acessar diferentes **bancos** do `MySQL` que estão alocados em máquinas e também em servidores.

De forma que permita a seleção de um banco pelo usuário que irá executar as rotinas neste banco selecionado. Se alguém souber como é feito para pegar a lista de bancos e tabelas destes na máquina e como é feito esse processo num link de servidor externo.

Creio que terei que pegar todos os `schema` dos **bancos**, mas não estou claro de qual arquivo e de como farei no caso do servidor.
Para todos os efeitos estou desenvolvendo em `Java` esse projeto.

Comment: vc sabe de antemão o nome do banco, senha, login, etc? ou vc tá querendo fazer um programa que vasculhe o computador do usuário atrás de bancos que vc não sabe o nome e endereco?

Comment: Sim ele tem que vasculhar os metadados pra descobrir os nomes dos BD e os nomes das tabelas e de seus campos, a senha e login será solicitada normalmente.

Comment: Sugiro procurar pelas portas `TCP/IP` abertas que esses bancos geralmente deixam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Código responsável em trazer uma lista de `Bancos de Dados` de um Servidor `MYSQL` e logo após escolhido um `Banco` mostrar suas `Tabelas`.

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {        
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
        try (Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/","root","senha")) {                        
            ResultSet result = conexao.createStatement().executeQuery("show databases;");
            System.out.println("Bancos de Dados");
            while (result.next()){
                System.out.println(result.getString(1));
            }            
            conexao.close();            
        }
        System.out.println("");        
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
        try (Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/generics","root","senha")) {                        
            ResultSet result = conexao.createStatement().executeQuery("show tables;");
            System.out.println("Tabelas de Banco de Dado Selecionado (Banco: generics)");
            while (result.next()){
                System.out.println(result.getString(1));
            }            
            conexao.close();            
        }        
    }
}
```

Perceba que o primeiro `getConnection` eu não passo o nome do `Banco` para que eu possa trazer a lista de todos os `Bancos` existentes nesse Servidor (comando `show databases`):

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/","root","senha")
```

Já no próximo `getConnection` eu passo o `Banco` *generics* e ele me trará as tabelas contidas nesse `Banco` (comando `show tables`):

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/generics","root","senha")
```

**Resultado obtido:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso foi para um banco localhost (loca da máquina), mas, se colocar o `ip externo` do `Servidor MYSQL` também tem o mesmo resultado ...